# Datetimepicker calendar hide while scrolling

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using eonasdan bootstrap 3 datetimepicker. When I click a picker icon, the calendar opens up. After I scroll with the mouse, the calendar is hidden. What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the `datepicker dialog` You can solve this by assigning your datepicker to a div like this.

HTML:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

From the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline:):

> Display the datepicker embedded in the page instead of in an overlay. Simply call .datepicker() on a div instead of an input.